# Show that $\iint f(x,y) d \lambda(y) d\lambda(x) \neq \iint f(x,y) d\lambda(x)d\lambda(y)$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
> 1, & x \geq 0, x\leq y <x+1\\
> -1, & x \geq 0, x+1 \leq y < x+2\\
> 0, & \text{in other case}
> \end{cases}$$
>   Show that $$\iint f(x,y) d \lambda(y) d\lambda(x) \neq \iint f(x,y) d\lambda(x)d\lambda(y)$$
>   where $\lambda$ stands for the lebesgue measure.

I literally have no clue on how to solve this, but I'd really like some hint instead of a complete answer to help me solve problems similar like this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Basically one just has to sit down and do the integrations. The first
way round is easier. For a fixed $x$, $f(x,y)$ can only be nonzero
if $x\ge0$. In that case, $f(x,y)=1$ for $y$ between $x$ and $x+1$
(so on an interval of length $1$) and $f(x,y)=-1$ for $y$ between $x+1$
and $x+2$ (so also on an interval of length $1$). It's zero for all other
$y$. Thus
$$\int f(x,y)\,dy=0$$
for any $x$, and so rather trivially then
$$\iint f(x,y)\,dy\,dx=0.$$

The other way round has more cases. I'll just do one of them.
If $0<y<1$, then $f(x,y)=1$ for $0\le x\le y$ and is zero otherwise.
So,
$$\int f(x,y)\,dx=y$$
if $0<y<1$. One then needs to delineate the other cases and
work out the integrals, and then finally do the double integral.